# Differences in string class implementations

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, implementation, utf-16

Why are string classes implemented in several different ways and what are the advantages and disadvantages? I have seen it done several differents ways

1. Only using a simple `char` (most basic way).
2. Supporting UTF8 and UTF16 through a templated string, such as `string<UTF8>`. Where `UTF8` is a `char` and `UTF16` is an `unsigned short`.
3. Having both a UTF8 and UTF16 in the string class.

Are there any other ways to implement a string class that may be better?

Comment: There is no perfect string class.  Performance, resource usage and universality are conflicting goals.  Pick the one that's popular on your operating system and its support libraries so you don't waste your time writing conversion code.  And please don't write your own string class, there are enough already.

Comment: I am aware that there is plenty of string classes, I would like to write one for the purpose of learning. Sure there is differernt ways to go about learning, but I have the time to spend on learning to write my own but I am just not sure of the differences so far.

Comment: @mmurphy: " I would like to write one for the purpose of learning". For me it is normally more productive to "learn by doing" and either write new things I *want to* write (fun) or things I *have to* write (work) instead of selecting obscure tasks for the "learning purposes". Your brain will forget everything you don't use or don't find interesting, ans making yet another string container isn't exactly a thrilling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` where `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` is not UTF16 encoding. There are more than 2^16 characters in unicode, and codes go at least up to `0xFFFFF` which is > `0xFFFF` (2byte `wchar_t` capacity). As a result, proper UTF16 should use variable number of bytes per letter (one 2byte `wchar_t` or two of them), which is not the case with `std::basic_string` and similar classes that assume that `one string element` == `one character`.

As far as I know there are two ways to deal with unicode strings.

1. Either use big enough type to fit any character into single string element (for example, on linux it is quite normal to see `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`), so you'll be able to enjoy "benefits" (basically, easy string length calculation and nothing else) of `std::string`-like classes.
2. Or use variable-length encoding (UTF8 - 1..4 bytes per char or UTF16 - 2..4 bytes per char), and well-tested string class that provides string-manipulation routines.

As long as you don't use `char` it doesn't matter which method you use. `char`-based strings are likely to cause trouble on machines with different 8bit codepage, if you weren't careful enough to take care of that (It is safe to assume that you'll forget about it and won't be careful enough - Microsoft Applocale was created for a reason).

Unicode contains plenty of non-printable characters  (control and formatting characters in unicode), so that pretty much defeats any benefit method #1 could provide. Regardless, if you decide to use method #1, you should remember that `wchar_t` is not big enough to fit all possible characters on some compilers/platforms (windows/microsoft compiler), and that `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` is not a perfect solution because of that.

---

Rendering internationalized text is PAIN, so the best idea would be just to grab whatever unicode-compatible string class (like [QString](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QString.html)) there is that hopefully comes with text layout engine (that can properly handle control characters and bidirectional text) and concentrate on more interesting programming problems instead.

---

-Update-

> If unsigned short is not UTF16, then what is, unsigned int? What is UTF8 then? Is that unsigned char?

**UTF16** is *variable-length* **character encoding**. UTF16 uses 1..**2** 2-byte (i.e. `uint16_t`, 16 bit) elements per character. I.e. number of of elements in UTF16 string != number of characters in string for UTF16. You can't calculate string length by counting elements.

**UTF8** is another *variable-length* encoding, based on 1byte elements (8 bit, 1 byte or "unsigned char"). One unicode character ("code point") in UTF8 takes 1..**4** `uint8_t` elements. Once again, number of elements in string != number of characters in string. The advantage of UTF8 is characters that exist within ASCII take exactly 1 byte per character in UTF8, which saves a bit of space, while in UTF16, character always takes at least 2 bytes.

**UTF32** is *fixed-length* **character encoding**, that always uses 32bit (4 bytes or `uint32_t`) per character. Currently any unicode character can fit into single UTF32 element, and UTF32 will probably remain fixed-length for a long time (I don't think that all languages of Earth combined would produce 2^31 different characters). It wastes more memory, but number of elements in string == number of characters in string.

Also, keep in mind, that C++ standard doesn't specify how big "int" or "short" should be.

Comment: If unsigned short is not UTF16, then what is, unsigned int? What is UTF8 then? Is that unsigned char?